# Does @Value annotation detect changes to the attribute ( in the property file) it injects

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a doubt, a part of my application's configuration resides in the properties file. This configuration will change at runtime. This configuration is encapsulated in a Config class.

```
class Config{
  @Value('mode.flag')
  String mode
}
```

If this property is manipulated at runtime when I fetch the value using `config.mode` will the changes be reflected or does spring inject the value only once?

Comment: It will inject it once.

Comment: Spring resolves `Value` annotations at application startup.
You should try something like this [spring-realoading-properties](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reloading-properties/)